# std::chrono::seconds: data type of the number of seconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

According to the reference, when you call `count()` on a `std::chrono::seconds` variable, you get the result as the data type `rep`. `Rep` is short for "representation".

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto count = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    auto sizeInBytes = sizeof(count);

    size_t countCasted = count; // The warning is produced for this line

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with C++14 for x86, I get following warning:

`warning C4244: "Initialization": Conversion from "_Rep" to size_t, possible loss of data`

- `sizeInBytes` on x86: 8
- `sizeInBytes` on x64: 8

Is `sizeof(count)` always 8? Why doesn't `count()` return `size_t`?

Comment: `sizeof(count)` is compiler/system-dependent. The C++ standard only places minimum requirements on the `rep` type, it does not require a specific size. It does require that it is signed, though (which makes sense since a difference could be negative). `size_t` has a very different purpose and is unsigned (which makes sense since an amount of memory cannot be negative).

Answer (score 1):

> Is sizeof(count) always 8?

It is not guaranteed to be.

> Why doesn't count() return size_t?

Because it is signed.